# Gingerbread ROM for Nook Color?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, nook-color

Does anyone know a good place to get a Gingerbread mod for Nook Color?

Comment: I would search the XDA forums (http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=864).  They have custom ROMS but don't know if any are Gingerbread.

Comment: Where have you already looked?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation, and the ROM I'm running is [Phiremod](https://sites.google.com/site/phiremod/)

I can definitely confirm it's Gingerbread, based on Cyanogenmod 7 and built specifically for the Nook Color.

Comment: my brother is using this one as well, and it works wonderfully and looks incredible.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the latest [ClockWorkMod Recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=971197) and then the latest [build](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=encore) of [CyanogenMod 7.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=960542).