# Vanilla Android on Nook Touch

Tags: vanilla-android, nook-simple-touch

I have a Nook Touch and I've followed some rooting instructions and have installed apps from Android Market, but some things about it are still Nook-ish, such as the screensaver.

How can I "wipe" my Nook Touch and install a "vanilla" version on Android and thus not run into anything specific to Nook?

Reminder: this is regarding the Nook Simple Touch eInk device, not the Nook Color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash a smartphone with vanilla Android ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/). You might also want to check [Vanilla Android on Nook Touch](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34135/)

Comment: @Izzy: The second question you link to is _this one_.

Comment: Ouch -- fail. Copied it the wrong way around I guess. I meant [Gingerbread ROM for Nook Color?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11726/)... To make up for it, some other helpful Q&As: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/) plus [Can I use an Android OS card on the new Nook Tablet?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/)